# Three "If" statements but only two "End If"?

Tags: vba

I found, in old VBA code, something strange. I expected the "If without Else", but nothing, it compiles:

```
Sub main()

Dim xyz As Integer
xyz = 10 'Not important

If xyz < 20 Then  'If #1

    If xyz <> 11 Then 'If #2

        If xyz = 10 Then _
            MsgBox ("10") 'If #3
    End If  'End if #1
    Else
        MsgBox ("ok")
        Exit Sub
    End If 'End if #2

End Sub   'No end if #3 ?
```

I don't want to reuse that code. I'm just curious about how it works, without third "End If".

Comment: The issue is the fact that the third if is actually a one line if statement with the `_` line break so it does not need the end if.

Comment: Using a line continuation character like that is just awful. The logical structure seems needlessly obscure even without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`If #3` is actually meant to be a single line of code by using the underscore character (aka [Line Continuation Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711641(v=vs.71).aspx)) `_`. This operator allows a line of code to wrap onto the next line in the editor so:

```
    If xyz = 10 Then _
        MsgBox ("10") 'If #3
```

Is actually:

```
    If xyz = 10 Then MsgBox ("10") 'If #3
```

You can write abbreviated `IF` statements this way. I see this regularly in old & new code.